# Ubuntu 20 network changes not in GUI or with nmtui are not reflected in netplan files

Tags: networking, server, 20.04

In Ubuntu I set from the GUI multiple network interfaces with both IPv4 and IPv6, on some static on others automatic.

I checked in `/etc/netplan` the `*.yaml` file and no changes are reflected here.

Why netplan file is not updated, even after reboot, and how can I force the OS to update the netplan file.

What I'm trying to do is to do a reverse check, make the modification in GUI, and see what happens in netplan "*yaml" files.

I read about netplan docs online, but I want to test different scenarios that I did not found in docs. I want to automate the writing the netplan yaml files this is why I want to see many configurations.

The Ubuntu version is Sever with desktop installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nmtui` stands for `NetworkManager` text user interface.
It is a front-end tool used to control the `NetworkManager` on a back-end.

`netplan` is also a front-end tool, which unifies configuration syntax for both `NetworkManager` and `systemd-networkd` back-ends.
You can select the `renderer` in the netplan configuration file.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

When you execute the netplan with `netplan apply` or during the system boot, it will create the configuration based on the selected renderer in appropriate location under `/run` directory.

Neither `NetworkManager` nor `systemd-networkd` are aware of the `netplan`.

I recommend very well written documentation: [Netplan.io](https://netplan.io/)